# How to delete a card from a list of cards (using API to extract Github user information onto a card that is presented in a list)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

This is a react project that uses an API to create a card which presents a Github users information. At the moment I am implementing a delete button on each card that would delete that specific card. You can try the application on code sandbox by [clicking here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/github-app-7cpur?file=/src/index.js:379-382). Instructions how to use: enter any 'Github' username into the input and click add card.

Once you click on add card, the user information is extracted into a Card which is then stored under CardList. This has an identifiable by key. But when clicking on Delete, instead of deleting the corresponding card to where the delete button is pressed, currently all the cards are deleted. (I have excluded the form component to make it easier to read).

Not sure if I am incorrectly using splice or not correctly declaring the cards key?

```
function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const addNewCard = cardInfo => {
    setCards(cards.concat(cardInfo));
  };

  const removeCard = key => {
    setCards(cards.splice(key, 0))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={addNewCard} />
      <CardList
        cards={cards}
        handleClick={removeCard}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const CardList = props => (
  <div>
    {props.cards.map((card, index) => (
      <Card {...card} key={index} handleClick={props.handleClick} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const Card = props => {
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "1em" }}>
      <img alt="avatar" style={{ width: "70px" }} src={props.avatar_url} />
      <div>
        <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{props.name}</div>
        <div>{props.blog}</div>
        <a href={props.html_url}>{props.html_url}</a>
        <button onClick={props.handleClick}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Just quickly looking at your code, key seems undefined or at least not what you intend to, as key is a prop of card, and you dont fill key with the id from the card, and your remove click is on the entire list.. so.. it needs some work

Comment: I think your right, but not sure how to tackle this... any hints or relevant examples would great.

Answer (score 0):

My error here was using splice instead of a slice. Since splice mutates the original array and that should be avoided. But by slicing the array up to the index which you would like to remove, you can then slice from the other side of the index that you would like to delete and concat the second slice to the first.

```
 const removeCard = key => {
    setCards(cards.slice(0, key).concat(cards.slice(key + 1, cards.length)))
  };
```

You can find the full code implementation below:

```
function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const addNewCard = cardInfo => {
    setCards(cards.concat(cardInfo));
  };

  const removeCard = key => {
     setCards(cards.slice(0, key).concat(cards.slice(key + 1, cards.length)))
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={addNewCard} />
      <CardList
        cards={cards}
        handleClick={removeCard}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const CardList = props => (
  <div>
    {props.cards.map((card, index) => (
      <Card {...card} key={index} handleClick={props.handleClick(index)} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const Card = props => {
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "1em" }}>
      <img alt="avatar" style={{ width: "70px" }} src={props.avatar_url} />
      <div>
        <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{props.name}</div>
        <div>{props.blog}</div>
        <a href={props.html_url}>{props.html_url}</a>
        <button onClick={props.handleClick}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```